# Passing DB values to modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I created a viewing module where users could view values from the database and I added an edit button, when you click the button, the modal should pop up with values based on the id.

Currently, this is what I'm getting when I click the edit button:

Now I'm still lacking one thing and it's the JavaScript which I already created:

```js
<script>
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
          var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
          var modal = $(this);
          var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "editdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    modal.find('.dash').html(data);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
    })
</script>
```

My `fetch.php` is purely PHP and I'm not sure how I would add the JS into it. Here's my `fetch.php`:

```js
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "seatrequest");
$output = '';
$colors = array();
$colors["Ongoing"] = "red";
$colors["Closed"] = "#00FF00";
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM request 
 WHERE req_date LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR reqname LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR natureofreq LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR postitle LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR critlevel LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR deadline LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR account LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR newaccname LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR lob LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR site LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR status LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM request ORDER BY reqnumber";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table bordered">
      <tr>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Date Requested</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Requested By</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Nature of Request</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Position Title</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Critical Level</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Deadline</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Account</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Name of Account (For New Seat)</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">LOB</th>
       <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Site</th>
                <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Status</th>
                <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Action</th>
                <th style="background-color: #e6ecff;">Edit</th>
      </tr>';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '<tr>
       <td>'.$row["req_date"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["natureofreq"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["postitle"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["critlevel"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["deadline"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["newaccname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["lob"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
                <td style="color:' . $colors[$row["status"]] . ';">' .$row["status"] . '</td>
                <td>
                 <form method="post" action="update-work-status.php">
                  <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                  <button class="fa fa-check" style="color: green" type="submit" name="approve" value=""></button><button class="fa fa-close" style="color: red" type="submit" name="decline" value=""></button>
                 </form>
                </td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="'.$row['reqnumber'].' ">Edit</a></td>
             </tr>
        ';
}  
echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}
?>
```

I guess my question is how would I incorporate that JS inside `fetch.php`? I'm not really sure if it's gonna work after adding the JS but I'll find out.

[Edit Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLWd5.png)

Comment: Pay attention on the request variable that you're using. You're making a GET request and, in PHP, fetching a POST request variable. Also, make sure that the file location is correct. For your JS script, the PHP file should be in the same folder as your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to your `fetch.php` from JS I'd create a data `array` and use the `POST` method like the following:

```
var dataString = {
  id: recipient,
  other: 'string'
}
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "fetch.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      modal.find('.dash').html(data);
  },
  error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
});
```

and in your `php`:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$other = $_POST['other'];
//Do something with your data
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hmm thanks, but I'm not sure where to put this exactly.

Comment: The first goes in your js file, the second can be placed everywhere in the `fetch.php`, usually at the beginning.

Comment: I mean how would I include the JS Script on my fetch.php?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can pass the data from js to php just specifying the url parameter. It's basically an http request. You should read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX or http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/